# File not getting output

Tags: ruby

Converting text from input file to morse code then placing results in an output txt file. File itself is being created but no output is being made.

```
MAXLINELENGTH = 40
codes = ['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '.', '..-.', 
         '--.', '....', '..', '.---', '-.-', '.-..', 
         '--', '-.', '---', '.--.', '--.-', '.-.', 
         '...', '-', '..-', '...-', '.--', '-..-', 
         '-.--', '--..','.----', '..---', '...--', 
         '....-', '.....', '-....', '--...', '---..', 
         '----.', '-----']
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
fin = File.open("input.txt", "r")
fout = File.open("output.txt", "w")
line_length = 0
while character = fin.getc
  if index = chars.index(character.upcase)
    morse = codes[index]
  elsif character == " "
    fout.print "    "
    line_length = line_length + 4
  end  
  if line_length >= MAXLINELENGTH
    fout.print "\n"
    line_length = 0
  end
end
fin.close
fout.close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never actually print the variable `morse`, you just assign it on the first line of the `if`-statement.

Comment: think I got it sorry new to stackoverflow :P